# Determining arguments passed to devops parameters in a pipeline run

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Lets say I have a devops pipeline with parameters defined like so:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: example1 
    displayName: Example 1 
    type: string 
    default: "An argument" 
  - name: example2
    displayName: Example 2 
    type: boolean 
    default: true
```

Which renders like this in the UI:

[image: Pipeline parameters]

If I run the pipeline, is there any way to see what arguments I passed to the parameters afterwards on the run screen? I know if the job is finished I can select `Run New` from build status page, and see the same branch and patameters. However, that is not available if the job has not finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, I suggest that you can click the **Target Pipeline run -> Click Job tab -> Check the log: Parent pipeline used these runtime parameters**, then you can see the value of the parameters.

For example:

[image]

Comment: I don't know how I missed that.